# Eager Loading Many to Many relationship with an Association Entity - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-4.5

I have a Many to Many relationship with an additional entity to manage the association.

Entities as below:

```
public class WorkOrderItem : EntityBase
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long WorkOrderItemId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<WorkOrderItemLanguage> WorkOrderItemLanguages { get; set; } 

}

 public class WorkOrderItemLanguage
{

    [Key, Column(Order = 0), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long WorkOrderItemId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string LanguageId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public LanguageType LanguageType { get; set; }

    public virtual WorkOrderItem WorkOrderItem { get; set; }
    public virtual Language Language { get; set; }
}


public class Language : EntityBase
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string LanguageId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string IsoCode { get; set; }
    public int Ordinal { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<WorkOrderItemLanguage> WorkOrderItemLanguages { get; set; } 

}
```

ModelBuilder Configurations

```
public class WorkOrderItemConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<WorkOrderItem>
{
    public WorkOrderItemConfiguration()
    {
        HasMany(x => x.WorkOrderItemLanguages).WithRequired(x => x.WorkOrderItem).HasForeignKey(x => x.WorkOrderItemId);
    }
}

public class LanguageConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Language>
{
    public LanguageConfiguration()
    {
        HasMany(x => x.WorkOrderItemLanguages).WithRequired(x => x.Language).HasForeignKey(x => x.LanguageId);
    }
}
```

if a produce a query to select a WorkOrderItem with all the languages that are related to it, how do i include the Language Entity?

the below query does not load the Language entity

```
 UnitOfWork.Set<WorkOrderItem>()
            .Include(x => x.WorkOrderItemLanguages.Select(l=>l.Language))
            .FirstOrDefault(x.WorkOrderItemId == id);
```

Comment: What is the value of `LanguageId` on the object that did not load the `Language` entity?

Comment: The specific value? It's from another database - looks like a GUID, but storing it as a string in my DB. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Is there a language with a `LanguageId` that matchs the string value?  I'd also not recommend to make your keys as strings.

Comment: All matches. I'm using Ashish's answer below which does work, but would prefer a strongly typed solution if possible.

Comment: Can you show your ModelBinder code?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by that?

Comment: Sorry I meant [ModelBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx).

Comment: Added Configurations, Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
var TesteEntities = UnitOfWork.Set<WorkOrderItem>()
        .Include("WorkOrderItemLanguages.Language")
        .FirstOrDefault(x.WorkOrderItemId == id);
```

and you will find Language here

Comment: `WorkOrderItemLanguage,WorkOrderItemLanguage.Language` is redundant, and can be simplified to `WorkOrderItemLanguage.Language`.

Comment: "A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'WorkOrderItem' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'WorkOrderItemLanguage'."

Comment: That does work, so have an upvote. Would prefer a strongly-typed Solution if possible?